# Can a service-check be limited to hosts with a custom attribute defined?

Tags: icinga

For those of our hosts, which have a public IP-address, we define a custom attribute in the host-definition: `_PADDR`:

```
define host {
        ...
        address 10....
        _paddr  53....
}
```

Can we then -- without creating specific groups or other entries -- limit a service check only to those of the hosts, which have the custom attribute defined?

Using Icinga-1.13.3.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Icinga 2.x support this. 1.x likely not

Comment: I'm with @uSlackr here..

Comment: @uSlackr, why don't you turn your comment into an answer so I can formally accept it and close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icinga 2.x supports this. I don't believe v1 does.  See the documentation [here](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/04-configuring-icinga-2/). Look specifically at the [Apply](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/04-configuring-icinga-2/#servicesconf), [Assign Where](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/04-configuring-icinga-2/#servicesconf), and [Custom Attributes](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/03-monitoring-basics/#custom-attributes)